# Blade templating '@extends' and '@section' not working

Tags: html, css, laravel-5

I'm trying out this new way of programming (It's new to me) which is Blade templating in combination with Laravel 5, now I've got it working without `@extends('layouts.master')` and `@section('content')` but when I try to add them, it doesn't work.

My `master.blade.php` file located in `views/layouts`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled</title>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
              </form>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
<div class="content">
    @yield('content')
</div>
```

My index.blade.php located in views:

```
@extends('layouts.master');
@section('content');
<div id="large-header" class="large-header">
    <canvas id="demo-canvas"></canvas>
    <h1 class="main-title"><span>Hello</i></span></h1>
    <h1 class="arrow-down"><a data-scroll href="#about"><img src="http://cdn.onnoschwanen.com/images/ui/arrow-down.svg"/></a></h1>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your `index.blade.php` on line 1 and 2.

The semicolon `;` isn't allowed in blade templating

Do this:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
<div id="large-header" class="large-header">
    <canvas id="demo-canvas"></canvas>
    <h1 class="main-title"><span>Hello</i></span></h1>
    <h1 class="arrow-down"><a data-scroll href="#about"><img src="http://cdn.onnoschwanen.com/images/ui/arrow-down.svg"/></a></h1>
</div>
```

And it should work just fine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you, I didn't even notice this!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@yield` command in the `master.blade.php` not in the `index.blade.php`.

Try this in your `master.blade.php` after the end of `nav` tag:

```
<content>
    @yield('content')
</content>
```

And remove from `index.blade.php` the `;` characters from 1st and 2nd lines.

[You can read the docs about blade templating.](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the semicolon in '@section('content');' worked for me. The semicolon is not allowed in blade templating.